# How to get average for specific list elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following part input file (has over 500 lines):

```
L1, a, b, 10, 20, pass,
L1, c, d, 11, 21, pass,
L1, e, f, 12, 22, pass,
L1, a, b, 13, 23, pass,
L1, e, f, 14, 34, pass,
```

I would like to get the average's of the duplicates i.e. the output as follows:

(where for L1, a, b, 11.5 = (10+13)/2, 21.5 = (20+23)/2)

```
L1, a, b, 11.5, 21.5
L1, c, d, 11, 21
L1, e, f, 13, 28
```

My current beginner python code is as follows- still working to tweak it better

```
 import csv
 from collections import defaultdict
 import numpy as np

 dd = defaultdict(list)
 with open("mean.csv") as input_file:
 for row in csv.reader(input_file):
            dd[tuple(row[:3])].append(float(row[3]))
            dd[tuple(row[:3])].append(float(row[4]))

 for k, v, m in dd.iteritems():
      if len(v) > 1:
           print (' '.join(k), np.mean(v), np.mean(m))
```

The error I get is:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "average.py", line 11, in <module>
      for k, v, m in dd.iteritems():
   ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Comment: You want to use the code snippet mtrw posted to my answer - and keep `for k, v in...` as it was...

Answer (score 6):

Untested, but something like this as base can be adapted for the other column... as this just does one at the moment.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

dd = defaultdict(list)
with open('in.csv') as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        dd[tuple(row[:3])].append(float(row[3]))

for k, v in dd.iteritems():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print ' '.join(k), np.mean(v)
```

Comment: To match the question, wouldn't you want your `print` to be something like `print ' '.join(k), np.mean(v)`?

Comment: +1 - you can have numpy do all the work if you want by doing `dd[tuple(row[:3])].append([row(3), row(4)])` and then `np.mean(np.array(v, dtype='float'), axis=0)`. Not as easy to read, but might be faster.

Comment: So I have some follow up questions: `I added a dd[tuple(row[:3])].append(float(row[4]))` to calculate the 2nd mean column but i got a need more than 2 values to unpack error.

Comment: @user1504774 Can you extend your question with - the code, the exact exception you're getting, and the value of `row` at the point of exception?

Answer (score 1):

With [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) this would be very short (and it should be fast).

You can do something like this (don't know the meaning or naming of your columns, so it depends what you want to use as the index of your `DataFrame`):

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('mean.csv', delimiter=',', header=None)

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
  X.1 X.2 X.3  X.4  X.5
0  L1   a   b   10   20
1  L1   c   d   11   21
2  L1   e   f   12   22
3  L1   a   b   13   23
4  L1   e   f   14   34

In [3]: df.groupby(['X.1', 'X.2', 'X.3']).mean()
Out[3]: 
              X.4   X.5
X.1 X.2 X.3            
L1   a   b   11.5  21.5
     c   d   11.0  21.0
     e   f   13.0  28.0
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with pandas but I will give this a shot too.

Comment: I had a look at your profile and saw that you asked a question tagged `pandas` before. although there are only two lines to solve your problems it's not that easy as you should learn something about `numpy` first and than some of the `pandas` api. However I think it is worth to do it!